# Chinese language support to web application

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to covert my web application to chinese. I have already changed my properties file format to UTF-8. But when I try to encode it, it's showing `java.lang.Exception` "file cannot be read". Any suggession how to do it what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A properties file must **not** be encoded in UTF-8. Read the [Properties class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store
>   properties from and to a character based stream in a simple
>   line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) /
>   store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the
>   load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output
>   stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that
>   cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using
>   Unicode escapes ; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape
>   sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files
>   to and from other character encodings.

I'm not sure this is the cause of your exception, though. Show us the code you're executing and the stack trace of the exception you're getting.

Comment: Hi..Its not showing much..Just showing one line exception.I got another solution http://konieczny.be/unicode.html this site helps me to convert my utf-8 text to html entries.I am just putting the text in my properties file.And it works.  Do you have any other solution please suggest me.. Thank you.